# Why are .stream file types used, how can I read these files in C++?

Tags: c++, file, binaryfiles

Essentially, I have I am given a stream of data and I am meant to process them into something meaningful, except I do not understand the sort of data I am given. For example, when I check the properties of that file it is a STREAM file. When I print the lines of that file I just get very weird characters?

Has anyone ever dealt with STREAM files in C++, any direction would be great

Thank you

Comment: There is no uniform "stream" file format, I suspect that it's just a file in an application-specific format which happens to be named like `somefile001.stream`. Windows Explorer doesn't know how to call it better than "STREAM file". There is no way to "read" the file unless you know or reverse-engineer its format. So the question you probably should be asking is "how to read these files from that application that supposedly contains such and such data, here is an example of file". The best scenario is to read the official documentation of the app.

Comment: Do you have any more context of these stream files (that is not a universal format), is it related to video ? audio ? produced by a specifc application ? etc.

Comment: @yeputons ah I see, I thought it served a specific function, it contains a mixture of little endians and binary encodings or so. The context is literally just encoded messages. So I guess, I will just have to read them as you probably would for files which contain binary encodings and little endians.